# What's wrong with this basic python select on windows?

Tags: python, windows, sockets, select

I'm having trouble using select. I just want a mean to know which clients are still there to receive data. There is my code :

```
import socket, select

server = socket.socket()
server.bind(('localhost',80))
server.listen(1)

answer = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
answer+= "Content-type: text/plain\r\n"
answer+= "Connection: close\r\n"
body = "test msg"
answer+= "Content-length: %d\r\n\r\n" % len(body)
answer+= body

clients = []

while True:
  nextclient,addr = server.accept()
  clients.append(nextclient)
  clients = select.select([],clients,[],0.0)[1]
  for client in clients:
    client.send(answer)
```

The select send me everytime all the sockets opened before, even if the connection was closed on the other end, this results in a Errno1053 : an etablished connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

I thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your select never blocks.

> A time-out value of zero specifies a poll and never blocks.

Also, your `listen` method's argument is absolutely extreme.

> socket.listen(backlog)
>
> Listen for connections made to the socket. The backlog argument specifies the maximum number of queued connections and should be at
>   least 0; the maximum value is system-dependent (usually 5)

Comment: This is not the cause of the error. I have the same problem with backlog from 1 to 5 and with different timeouts for select. Anyway i don't want a block there, i just want to know which clients are ready for writing.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you never close a socket after writing to it and you don't as well remove it from `clients`.

Besides, you overwrite `clients` so that your list of clients is lost; some clients will never be processed.

Something like

```
    clients_now = select.select([],clients,[],0.0)[1]
    for client in clients_now:
        client.send(answer)
        client.close()
        clients.remove(client)
```

might help.

BTW, just a small block of 1 or 10 ms will keep your server responsive, but prevents a high CPU load because of idle waiting.

BTW2: Maybe you should include your server socket in the select process as well...

Comment: Normally when i do clients = select ( .. clients ..) i keep in clients the clients ready to receive data. Yet it turns out that i keep every client once accepted even when they closed the socket. So your suggestion doesn't change anything. Moreover, sockets are automatically closed when garbage collected. So sockets no ready to receive data are automatically closed in my code.

Comment: But if you don't get a notification about if the peer has closed, you keep on sending and sending the same data all over again. Plus, a client which is delayed might drop out of `clients` too early because it is not ready yet. Better way is to actively announce that you are finished with sending by losing the socket (which is nevertheless good style) and removing from the list-to-be-watched.